# Is there any other way to wait for data coming from Ajax call in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I was facing n issue of data is "undefined" when ajax call takes time to return data,  to fix that I have checked the data using turnery operator in Render method and it's working perfectly, is this correct what I am doing here or it can be resolved in a better way.

I was using the following which resulted in the error because it was waiting for the data.

`<Table bordered columns={columns} dataSource={profile.data.data} />`

When I used following it worked

`{profile.data ? <Table bordered columns={columns} dataSource={profile.data.data} /> : ''}`

My component file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'dva';
import { Table } from 'antd';

@connect(({ profile }) => ({
  profile,
}))
class WorkAccess extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
   const { dispatch } = this.props;
   dispatch({ type: 'profile/Workaccess' });
 }

  render() {
   const { profile } = this.props;
   const columns = [
      { title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', key: 'Name' },
      { title: 'Privilege', dataIndex: 'privilege', key: 'Workacess' },
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        {profile.data ? <Table bordered columns={columns} dataSource={profile.data.data} /> : ''}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WorkAccess;`
```

Comment: use this instead
`profile.data && profile.data!=null && profile.data!=undefined? render here : ""`

Answer (score 0):

What you are is almost alright, one improvement you can make is:
instead of

```
{profile.data ? <Table bordered columns={columns} dataSource={profile.data.data} /> : ''}
```

You can:

```
if(!profile.data)
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;  // You can show some loading comonent here, instead of just writing loading
return (
  <div>
    <Table bordered columns={columns} dataSource={profile.data.data} />
  </div>
);
```

You can use *async await* if you wish for api call to complete, but I wouldn't recommend it, you should show the user something while you are fetching data from server. You can async await like this:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    await dispatch({ stuff })
}
```

But in this case it will not work because `componentDidMount` get called after mount and if component has mounted the error has already occured, and you shouldn't use `componentWillMount` as it's deprecated. You will have to async await in parent component somewhere. But don't go through all that trouble, just do what I suggested above.